# How to paint the edges of an object?

Tags: texturing, materials, edges

I kindly ask you for help with my project. This is one of my first models and I would like to finish it, however, I suck at materials and texturing.

My model:
[image]

Reference:
[image]

-How do I create this yellow detail running the edges all the way of the guitar body and around these cut-out holes?

-How can I add these white details at the top? "Ibanez" and this little symbol

-How to texture this dark-orange part in the center?

-How to create ivory-like material for fret indicators? (multiple white rectangles across the neck)

-Do you have any idea how to create good-looking knobs? (these 4 cylinders at the bottom of the body)

-Why does my lightning/render suck?

If you can help me with 1 or more of these problems I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance! Have fun modeling everybody.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Welcome to SE. Your question is really excellent and also it is pretty clear what you want - this is not a matter of course. But...a small improvement request -> because i don't want the moderators to close your question, you should only ask one question here. Not 5. Just open 4 other questions with copied pics + text, but just one question. Then you will make good experience in this nice community.

Comment: and you should hurry up with this -> you already got one close vote. A bit motivation: i got this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfhnJ.png, with these nodes: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6EeE.png but i think, you are not happy with this, since your guitar is already looking pretty perfect. But maybe it is a starting point to experiment with...

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1. The yellow detail looks like where real life beveling cut away real life paint, and thankfully the bevel modifier in blender allows you to change the material for what it bevels. However, you might have to undo some of the beveling you’ve already done. If that isn’t practical for you, I would use Select Edge Loops to select the appropriate faces, and then assign a yellow material to them.
2. To create the white detail, I would advise you to create a Text object, convert it to mesh, join it with the current mesh, and use Intersect (knife) to put the faces on the guitar mesh. Then you can assign a white material to it.
3. Use a Color Ramp node set to mostly black with a little yellow, and control it with a Noise texture.
4. This looks like a job for Subsurface Scattering, but I’m not sure. You may try using a noise texture to alter the normals, and then turn on Clearcoat on top of that (Principled BSDF only). The clearcoat in Principled BSDF has its own separate normals, so this may be your best shot.
5. Difficult to tell since the knobs are being viewed directly from the top, but I would start with drawing the profile of the side of the knob, then spinning it. Getting the grip into the knob would probably then be a matter of intersect (Boolean), and some beveling. However, this may not work for you.
6. Your material roughnesses look like they are at the default 0.5, and the top of your guitar is perfectly flat. I might try turning the roughness down, and maybe using a custom normal map or actually editing the guitar face so that it is curved. Most electric guitars I’ve seen actually did not appear curved, but they were definitely very glossy. If the roughness setting doesn’t work like you want, try using clearcoat (Principled BSDF shader only) to simulate a glossy finish on the guitar body.

[More information on Shader Nodes](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/index.html)

[More information on Materials.](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/index.html)